# Send realtime jmeter active threads on all slaves during remote testing to influxdb via jsr223 listner

Tags: jmeter, jsr223

How the send  realtime jmeter active threads on all slaves during remote testing to influxdb via jsr223 listner

Answer (score 0):

Any reason for not using JMeter's [Backend Listener](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-grafana-to-monitor-jmeter-non-gui-results-part-2)? This way you will get way more data without having to implement your custom solutions, you will have the number of active threads along with [other metrics](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/realtime-results.html#metrics) plotted:

[image]

---

If you still want an example Groovy code for the JSR223 Listener to add your custom metric with the custom tags to the custom database here is some sample you can use as a basis:

```
def influxHost = '192.168.99.100'
def influxPort = '8086'
def database = 'mydb'

def ip = org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getLocalHostIP()
def hostname = org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.getLocalHostName()
def activeThreads = ctx.getThreadGroup().numberOfActiveThreads()

def client = org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder.create().build()
def post = new org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost('http://' + influxHost + ':' + influxPort + '/write?db=' + database)
def entity = new org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity('active_threads,host=' + hostname + ',ip=' + ip + ' value=' + activeThreads + ' ' + System.nanoTime())
post.setEntity(entity)
client.execute(post)
```

More information: [Write data using the InfluxDB API](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/guides/writing_data/#write-data-using-the-influxdb-api)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I already tried the backend listener, but I need to differentiate requests from transactions the backend listener does not allow that, so i wrote a jsr223 script to resolve this problem. I will try your script .